# How lo list children of each node in a Binary Search Tree from preorder traversal?

Tags: c++, loops, binary-search-tree, traversal, preorder

Given a preorder traversal as int vector (for example {7,4,3,6,5,8,10}), how could I list 
iteratively the children of each node?

```
Example output
7 - 4 8
4 - 3 6
6 - 5
8 - 10
```

I made it generating a tree and then listing each child recursively, but I need to do it only using the given vector. Any idea?

I'm not asking for the code, just some cool ideas

Comment: pay attention to fact that right child is greater than parent and left one is lesser

Comment: There happens to be a fairly simple way to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper, and write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write entire programs for other people, here, and always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Use a `std::stack<int>`, and iterate through the list using some logic in manipulating the stack.  There is no need for recursion.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I made it. For each iteation, you have to found greater and lesser element, print them, and set them as used to avoid printing values from other branches.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int preOrder[] = {7,4,3,6,5,8,10};
    int size = sizeof(preOrder)/sizeof(int);
    bool used[size] = {false};
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        bool lesserFound = false;
        bool greaterFound = false;
        for(int j = i+1; j < size; ++j){
            if(used[j]==true)
                lesserFound=greaterFound=true;

            if(preOrder[j]<preOrder[i] && lesserFound==false){
                cout << preOrder[i] << " - LeftChild: " << preOrder[j] << endl;
                lesserFound=true;
                used[j]=true;
            }else if(preOrder[j]>preOrder[i] && greaterFound==false){
                cout << preOrder[i] << " - RightChild: " << preOrder[j] << endl;
                greaterFound=true;
                used[j]=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
7 - LeftChild: 4
7 - RightChild: 8
4 - LeftChild: 3
4 - RightChild: 6
6 - LeftChild: 5
8 - RightChild: 10
```